# Selenium - What strategies for get link?

Tags: html, selenium, web-crawler, abot

I have many web elements like this

```html
<a data-control-name="browsemap_profile" href="/in/quyen-nguyen-63098b123/" id="ember278" class="pv-browsemap-section__member ember-view">    <img width="56" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQFHZ41UPexTLQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1599091200&amp;v=beta&amp;t=lkoiKVK58W1tciUEc5UUohvEsa99lLTv66a1PJ4hp5k" loading="lazy" height="56" alt="member_name" id="ember279" class="lazy-image pv-browsemap-section__member-image EntityPhoto-circle-4 ember-view">



    <div class="pv-browsemap-section__member-detail">
      <h3 id="ember280" class="pv-browsemap-section__member-detail--has-hover actor-name-with-distance ember-view">  <span class="name-and-icon"><span class="name">Quyen Nguyen</span>
      <span class="distance-and-badge">
        <span data-test-distance-badge="" id="ember281" class="distance-badge separator ember-view"><span class="visually-hidden">
    2nd degree connection
</span>
<span class="dist-value">2nd</span>
</span><!---->      </span>
</span>


</h3>
      <p class="pv-browsemap-section__member-headline t-14 t-black t-normal">
        <div style="line-height:2rem;max-height:4rem;-webkit-line-clamp:2;" id="ember282" class="inline-show-more-text inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed-with-line-clamp ember-view">I'm looking for IT Director/Admissions Director/Training Head/Marketing Director

<!---->
<!----></div>
      </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

I want to get a list of data like this `/in/quyen-nguyen-63098b123/`? How many way to select then get this data?

I also want to get a list of id in pattern: `ember278`, `ember279` , `ember238` , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```cs
IEnumerable<IWebElement> connectionBlocks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@id[starts-with(., 'ember') and string-length() > 5]]"));
```

Then use regular expression for next parsing.